# Moving mysql database to another computer

Tags: mysql, database

I have a highschool project that involves a server and a mysql database and I have some problems with mysql. The "server" program is going to accept requests then connect to the database and extract some data. The first problem is that I can't connect mysql to visual studio 2015. The mysql server doesn't appear in the options panel when setting the connection. I tried installing and reinstalling mysql server but nothing happens. My second problem is that I will write the application on my PC and then move it on another computer. Do I have to connect everything to mysql again? And the most important thing do I need to install visual studio on that computer too? I use mysql 5.7. And installed the last version of the connector but I found out that it doesn't support visual studio and the connector should be in the windows installer but I don't find any way to install it.

Sorry if this question is against the rules, but my instructors doesn't explain anything and I can't find any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There is no evidence of a problem with your mysql installation. The issue is that Visual Studio does not know how to connect to the database. You need to install and configure the MySQL odbc drivers on the machine where visual studio / where your application will run.

Comment: I resolved the first problem, but the second question still remains:  If I move the program and open another mysql server and make the connection again, will i have to change just the connection string?